# How to match string with another string that is almost the same (fuzzy matching)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

In Rails, I am passing in a string: 'AE18BX21'. I am querying the database to find strings that match with the input string. However the input string and the string in the database sometimes don't match up. Sometimes there is an extra letter/number, sometimes a letter/number is missing, or sometimes the letter/number is a different letter/number.

I have tried a few different regex expressions like:

```
Table.where("string =~ ?", 'A+E+1+8+B+X+2+1')

Table.where("string =~ ?", '(A|.)+(E|.)+(1|.)+(8|.)+(B|.)+(X|.)+(2|.)+(1|.)')
```

In an ideal world, I would want it to return only the strings that match up `80%` or more.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like Levenshtein distance, but not sure what db engine you are using and if it supports it. Related to your first regex you might try: `Table.where("string =~ ?", 'A*E*1*8*B*X*2*1*')`

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't thought about the Levenshtein distance. I am using PostgresSQL. Ill check into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading your question, I think you want something like Levenshtein distance, and as you stated in your comment, for Postgres you could use it.

Quoting its documentation here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/fuzzystrmatch.html

```
test=# SELECT levenshtein('GUMBO', 'GAMBOL');
 levenshtein
-------------
           2
(1 row)

test=# SELECT levenshtein('GUMBO', 'GAMBOL', 2,1,1);
 levenshtein
-------------
           3
(1 row)

test=# SELECT levenshtein_less_equal('extensive', 'exhaustive',2);
 levenshtein_less_equal
------------------------
                      3
(1 row)

test=# SELECT levenshtein_less_equal('extensive', 'exhaustive',4);
 levenshtein_less_equal
------------------------
                      4
(1 row)
```

Then you can build your sql query with your desire distance:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable
WHERE levenshtein(string , 'AE18BX21') <= 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. Helped a lot. I will get the fuzzystrmatch installed into postgres and this will be amazing!